# How, in R, do I access numbered data sets with the loop variable?

Tags: r

Can someone please tell me how, in R, I can access numbered data sets with the loop variable?
So, if I have a long list of files in each of which I need to find all the places where a particular value is in the second column and take the corresponding value in the same row in the third column and list these all in one file, how might I do this?  The files are named by the title of the folder, date, and time, respectively, in this fashion, "name_0619_0123". There are the same number of files per each day, and they are at the times every day.  Therefore if there is a command that can somehow let me access a file in such a way that I can have a variable (dependent on the loop counting variable) in the string that I give for the file name in the command, I can access a different file per each loop iterations.

Any and all ideas please

Also, if there is a more appropriate place for me to ask this question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably lots of ways to do this in R:

You can use a command line script (see the [R documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scripting-with-R)).

i.e.

```
R CMD BATCH "--args arg1 arg2" foo.R &
```

Where `foo.R` is your R script and the `args` can be the loop varaibles you are interested in.

Another way to do this is to use [regular expressions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html) to parse out information from your file names.

If you provide a more concrete example I'll be able to show you some more specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some guidelines if you can glob those files you need to process either with a pattern or picking up all of them.

You may generate a list of files with `list.files`, read them in one shot with `lapply`, `read.csv`, and fetch what you need into a `data.frame` with a single row. Then, using `do.call`, `rbind`, and your list of data.frames, you can combine everything into a single data.frame without even writing `for` explicitly.